# Properties of substitution system

Tags: recurrence-relations, computer-science, substitution

I'm interested in automatic sequence or substitution systems.
I focused on the simplest form with a binary alphabet without constants.
A well-known example is [Thue-Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence)
with axiom `[0]`  and rules `[ [0] → [0, 1], [1] → [1, 0] ]`
It is known that it's uniformly recurrent word( or almost periodic ) and [fractal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_sequence).
On the other hand, it is not normal or equidistributed.
in the sense that subwords are presented unequally.
E.g.  3-tuples `[0, 1, 0],[1, 0, 1],[1, 0, 0],[0, 0, 1],[0, 1, 1],[1, 1, 0]]`
the same quantity   but there are no `[0,0,0] and [1,1,1]`.

Such sequences can be visualized by turtle graphics (or AnglePath).
Thue-Morse produces Koch curve for 60°

[image]

but primitive picture for 90°
[image]

Exploring various substitution rules I've found next example:
**UPD**  Recently found a simpler example

`init [0], [[0,0] -> [1], [0] → [0, 0], [1] → [1, 0]]`

Turtle graphics for it looks very interesting:
60°:

[image]

90°:

[image]

Two questions are raised.

1. Such properties as fractality and almost periodicity are strictly defined for *infinite sequences.* Is it possible to formulate a computational criterion for *the degree* of these properties for finite sequence?
2. I’ve done some preliminary calculations, and it looks like the difference between "my" sequence and Thue-Morse is *only quantitative*. But turtle graphics look *very* different. What properties might be behind this?